# Link to anchor in bootstrap accordion content from joomla menu item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I have a joomla 3+ test website running bootstrap 3. I have an article with content in an accordion panel, which is working just fine. Does anyone know how to add a link from a joomla menu to an anchor tag within the accordion content. I have tried using menu type external content with the full url of the page with the article and appending #menuLink to the url for the link and then adding an My content to the place within the accordion content but no joy ...
Thanks in advance to anyone who can solve this mystery. I am a bit of a newbie so if anyone replies needs to be simple instructions

Comment: Have you tried external url?

Comment: yes I have, see my original post "I have tried using menu type external link"